# How to solve "Linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)?"

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone, xcode

Anyone who encounter this problem?

How to solve it?

Please see attached.

Linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation):

[image]

Got the error run into device.

Thank you in advance :)

Comment: Build with bitcode enabled, or disable bitcode for the target?  You have to read more than just the error message to get context.

Comment: Got it already. Thank you so much :)

Answer (score 3):

I've experienced this problem as well. The solution was to Enable Bitcode for ALL Podfiles:

[image]

Comment: I did, but got the same error :)

Answer (score 1):

Please Select Your target Setting==>Build Setting==>Build Option and Select Enable Bitcode=yes.

[image: Please Follow This Step.]

Comment: Got the same error also :)

Comment: Any Third Party Library are used in Project? @AnneBernadette

Comment: I see. Got it, enable bitcode into multiple values, debug; No & release; Yes :)